# How can I get a document in mongoose that have the current time in range of two Date values in a doc?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am making an api to fetch an ongoing/next exam using mongoose, I have two values: startTime and endTime in the model, and I want to fetch the current exam that is ongoing:
(PS: I used fastify)
Model:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const { SchemaTypes } = require("mongoose")

const ExamsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  startTime: SchemaTypes.Date,
  endTime: SchemaTypes.Date,
  subject: SchemaTypes.String,
})

const Exams = mongoose.model("Exams", ExamsSchema)

module.exports = { Exams }
```

and I tried to do this but it returns "none" every time(I already have 2 test exams in the database, there's no problem with the db):
[api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MS7b.png)

```js
fastify.get('/', async function (request, reply) {
  const exam = await Exams.findOne({
    $where: function () {
      const now = Date.now()
      return this.startTime.valueOf() > now > this.endTime.valueOf()
    }
  })
  
  if (exam) {
    reply.send({msg: "ongoing", ...exam._doc})
  } else {
    const nextExam = await Exams.find({
      $where: () => {
        const now = Date.now()
        return (now < this.startTime.valueOf())
      }
    })[0]
    if (nextExam) {
      reply.send({msg: "next", ...nextExam})
    } else {
      reply.send({msg: "none"})
    }
  }
})
```

Two of the docs in the db:

```json
{
  "startTime": {
    "$date": "2021-07-21T04:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endTime": {
    "$date": "2021-07-21T05:30:00.000Z"
  },
  "subject": "SomeSubject"
}
```

```json
{
  "startTime": {
    "$date": "2021-07-21T03:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "endTime": {
    "$date": "2021-07-21T04:30:00.000Z"
  },
  "subject": "SomeSubject"
}
```

The current time is 2021-07-21T03:35:00.000Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$where` there - in general, avoid `$where` - it's an expensive operation - it provides great flexibility, but requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection.

use smth like this:

```
let now = new Date();
...
.find({
  $and: [
    {startTime: {$lte: now}},
    {endTime: {$gt: now}}
  ]})
```

Also, side note - `4 < 3 < 5` is true, due it executes `4 < 3` first and then `false < 5 === true`

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to backend and js

Comment: Also I think that the syntax of $and should be   
`$and: [{startTime: {$lte: now}}]`

Comment: Yeah, missed the curly braces, will fix that

Comment: You don't need an `$and`, just `find({ startTime: {$lte: now}, endTime: {$gt: now} })`